# Title from Id Youtube API v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out the youtube API v3, and one thing I'm trying to do is getting the title of the video if you have the video Id already, I have seen some other people doing this, but I haven't found any simple straightforward example code of how to do this.

So I have set up a super simple *"starting point demo"*, with this code how would I make it so you type the ID of the video in the text-field and then press get title and the ytTitle div text updates with the title of the video.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3tggc003/1/)**

**CODE (HTML):**

```
<input id="textbox_id" placeholder="YT ID here" type="text" />
<button id="btnGetTitle">GetTitle</button>
<div id="ytTitle">Title Name here</div>
```

**CODE (Javascript/jQuery):**

```
  var varID = "78RUGbKkMFI"; //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78RUGbKkMFI
  var varApiKey = "AIzaSyDDBk8tAkod1VRRNyFZF09fgQyMpnSe5HI"; //https://console.developers.google.com

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetTitle").click(
            function () {
                ChangeText();
            }            
        );
    });

function ChangeText() {
   $('#ytTitle').text('Title');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solved it:

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3tggc003/3/)**

**CODE (HTML):**

```
<input id="textbox_id" placeholder="YT ID here" type="text" />
<button id="btnGetTitle">GetTitle</button>
<div id="ytTitle">Title Name here</div>
```

**CODE (JavaScript/jQuery):**

```
  var varID = '78RUGbKkMFI';
  var varApiKey = 'AIzaSyDDBk8tAkod1VRRNyFZF09fgQyMpnSe5HI';

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetTitle").click(
            function () {
            getVids ($('#textbox_id').val()); //varId
            }            
        );
    });

function getVids(vid){
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
    part: 'snippet', 
    id: vid, 
    key: varApiKey},
      function(data){
      ChangeText(data.items[0].snippet.title);
      }
  )
}


function ChangeText(titleText) {
   $('#ytTitle').text(titleText);
}
```